# É possível instalar perlapi 5.14.2 no Debian 9?

Tags: linux

Estou tentando instalar o pacote perlapi-5.14.2 em um servidor linux Debian 9 e estou tendo o seguinte retorno:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package perlapi-5.14.2 is a virtual package provided by:
perl-base 5.14.2-21+deb7u5 [Not candidate version]
perl-base 5.14.2-21+deb7u3 [Not candidate version]
```

Pelas minhas pesquisas, parece que não temos esse pacote no repositório do Debian 9. É possível eu instalar esse pacote, pelo terminal, buscando em outro repositório? Tipo usando wget + link?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro tente da update (Para atualizar os sources):

```
sudo apt-get update
```

E tente instalar novamente, se não funcionar tente:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Assim ele vai ajustar as dependências e tente instalar novamente, mas se mesmo assim não funcionar tente utilizar o aptitude:

```
sudo aptitude install perlapi-5.14.2
```

Comment: Executei os dois primeiros comandos e tentei reinstalar, nao foi. Mesmo retorno. Executei o terceiro comando e tive o seguinte retorno:

    sudo: aptitude: command not found

Comment: tente 'sudo apt-get install aptitude'